# how to use a custom hook without event listener

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I want to check if the user is connected with a fresh token before showing the component, if not, it refreshes it by using `getToken()` which is inside the custom hook `useGetToken()`. But is it possible to launch the `getToken()` without an event listener? to change the state values of token and `expireAt` in the **AsyncStorage**?

Here is the component:

```
const User = () => {
     const { getToken, token, expireAt, error } = useGetToken();
     useEffect(() => {
        const checkUserToken = async () => {
            try {
                const data = await getAll();
                if (data.length > 0) {
                    const storedToken = data[0][1];
                    const storedExpire = new Date(data[1][1]);
                    const storedEmail = data[2][1];
                    console.log("Token Stored: " + storedToken);

                    if (storedToken != '' && storedToken) {
                        console.log("now: " + new Date());
                        console.log("expire: " + storedExpire);
                        if (storedExpire > new Date()) {
                            console.log("-> not expired");
                            setIsConnected(true);
                        }
                        else {
                            console.log("-> token expired");
                            //TODO rente pas dans la fonction
                            () => getToken(storedEmail);     // It doesn't enter here
                            if (error)
                                console.log("ERROR axios: " + error);
                            else {
                                console.log("Storing new data token : " + token);
                                console.log("Storing new expire: " + expireAt);

                                await storeData({ token: token, expire: expireAt });
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } else
                    setIsConnected(false);
            } catch (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        };

        checkUserToken();
    }, []);
  

    return (
        <>
            {isConnected ?
                (<UserOptions callBack={handleCallbackIsConnected} />)
                : (<Login callBack={handleCallbackIsConnected} />)}
        </>
    );
};
```

here is the custom hook:

```
export const useGetToken = () => {
    const [token, setToken] = useState('');
    const [expireAt, setExpire] = useState('');
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);
    const getToken = (email) => {
        console.log("INTO getToken");
        axios.post('http://localhost:8080/api/auth/refresh', email)
            .then(function (response) {
                setToken(response.data.result.token);
                setExpire(response.data.result.expire)
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                setError(error.message);
            })
        }
        console.log("INTO useGetToken : " + token);
        return { getToken, token, expireAt, error };
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the reflesh of the token from the api and to store it, here is another way to solve using another `useEffect` with `asyncstorage`

```
import { getAll, storeToken } from '../../utils/storage';
import { getAuthToStore } from '../../hooks/queries-hook';

const User = () => {
    const [token, setToken] = useState('');
    const [expireAt, setExpire] = useState('');
    const [isConnected, setIsConnected] = useState(false);
useEffect(() => {
        const checkUserToken = async () => {
            try {
                const data = await getAll();
                if (data.length > 0) {
                    const storedToken = data[0][1];
                    const storedExpire = new Date(data[1][1]);
                    const storedEmail = data[2][1];
                    console.log("Token Stored: " + storedToken);

                    // si ya bien des tokens
                    if (storedToken != '' && storedToken) {
                        // qu'ils ne sont pas expiré
                        console.log("now: " + new Date());
                        console.log("expire: " + storedExpire);
                        if (storedExpire > new Date()) {
                            console.log("-> not expired");
                            setIsConnected(true);
                        }
                        else {
                            console.log("-> token expired");
                            getAuthToStore({ email: storedEmail })
                                .then(item => {
                                    setToken(item.data.token);
                                    setExpire(item.data.expire);
                                    setIsConnected(true);
                                })
                                .catch(function (error) {
                                    console.log("error getToStore : " + error);
                                })
                        }
                    }
                } else
                    setIsConnected(false);
            } catch (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        };

        checkUserToken();
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        const storeAll = async () => {
            await storeToken({ token: token, expire: expireAt });
        }
        if (token && token != '')
            storeAll();
    }, [token]);
```

not a custom hook anymore `getAuthToStore()`

```
export const getAuthToStore = (email) => {    
    return axios.post('http://10.0.2.2:8080/api/auth/refresh', email)
}
```

And to store the token:

```
export const storeToken = async (props) => {
    try {
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('token', props.token)
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('expire', props.expire)
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a service, such as authService, and save the getToken() method there. You can then use the method both in the hook, and inside the component by importing it.

```
import authService from './auth-service.js';


const Component = () => {
...
   // call here get token method
   const res = authService.getToken(email);
...

}
```